# Dataset for RNN-LSTM as Spell checker in python

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, spell-checking, recurrent-neural-network

I have dataset of more than 5 million of records which has many noise features(words) in it So i thought of doing spell correction and abbreviation handling.

When i googled for spell correction packages in python i got packages like [autocorrect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocorrect/0.2.0), [textblob](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html), [hunspell](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hunspell) etc and [Peter norvig's method](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html)

Below is the sample of my dataset

```
Id      description
 1      switvch for air conditioner..............
 2      control tfrmr...........
 3      coling pad.................
 4      DRLG machine
 5      hair smothing kit...............
```

I Tried spell correction function by above packages using the code

```
dataset['description']=dataset['description'].apply(lambda x: list(set([spellcorrection_function(item) for item in x])))
```

For entire dataset it took more than 12 hours to complete spell correction and also it introduces few noise( for 20% of total words which are important)

for eg: In last row, "smothing" corrected as "something" but it should be "smoothing" ( i dont get "something" in this context)

**Approaching Further**

When I observed the dataset not all time the spelling of word is wrong, there were also correct instance of spelling somewhere in dataset.So I tokenize the entire dataset and split correct words and wrong words by using [dictionary](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt) , applied jarowinkler similarity method between all pair of words and selected pairs which is having similarity value 0.93 and more

```
  Wrong word   correct word  similarity score
    switvch      switch           0.98
    coling       cooling          0.98
    smothing     smoothing        0.99
```

I got more than 50k pair of similar words which I put in dictionary with wrong word as key and correct word as value

I also kept words with its abbreviation list( ~3k pairs) in dictionary

```
 key     value
 tfrmr   transformer
 drlg    drilling
```

Search and replace key-value pair using code

```
dataset['description']=dataset['description'].replace(similar_word_dictionary,regex=true)



dataset['description']=dataset['description'].replace(abbreviation_dictionary,regex=true)
```

This code took more than a day to complete for only 10% of my entire dataset which I found is not efficient one.

Along With Python packages I had also found [deep spelling](https://machinelearnings.co/deep-spelling-9ffef96a24f6) which is something very efficient way of doing spelling correction.There was a very clear explanation of RNN-LSTM as spell checker.

As I dont know much about RNN and LSTM i got very basic understanding of above link.

**Question**

I am confused how to consider trainset  for RNN to my problem, 
 whether

1. I need to consider correct words ( without any spelling mistake) in entire dataset as trainset and  entire description of my dataset as testset.
2. or Pair of similar words and abbrievation list as trainset and description of my dataset as testset ( where model find wrong word in description and correct it)

or any other way? could some one please tell me how can I approach further

Answer (score 0):

Could you give some more information about the model you are building?
It makes sense to use a character level sequence to sequence model, similar to the one [you would use for translation](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html). There are already some approaches trying to do the same ([1](https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-a-spell-checker-with-tensorflow-d35b23939f60), [2](https://machinelearnings.co/deep-spelling-9ffef96a24f6), [3](https://medium.com/@yaoyaowd/rnn-spelling-correction-to-crack-a-nut-with-a-sledgehammer-7f5aa442c08c)).
Maybe draw on them for some inspiration?

Now, with regards to the dataset, It seems that the one you are trying to use mostly has errors? If you don't have the **correct** version of each phrase, I don't think you can use this dataset.

A simple approach would be to get an existing dataset and introduce random noise in it. The [deep spelling blog](https://machinelearnings.co/deep-spelling-9ffef96a24f6) talks about how you can do that an existing text corpus. Also, a recommendation from myself would  be to use small-ish standalone sentences as the training set. A good place to find those is from machine translation datasets (like the [tatoeba](https://tatoeba.org/eng/downloads) project) and only use the english phrases. Out of those you can create pairs of (`input_phrase`, `target_phrase`) where the `input_phrase` is potentially noisy (but not always).

With regards to performance, firstly 12hrs training for 1 pass of a 5M dataset sounds about right for a home pc. You can use a GPU or a cloud solution ([1](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/using-gpus), [2](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb)) for faster training.

Now for false-positive correction, the dictionary you have created could indeed be handy: if a word exists in this dictionary, don't accept a "correction" on it from the model.